# Lightweight syntax and nested records

Tags: f#, mono, nested, record

This program:

```
type A = { a : int }
type B = { b : A }

//34567890
let r = {
  b = {      // line 6
    a = 2    // line 7 
  } 
}
```

Produces under mono/fsharpc this warning *twice*:

> /Users/debois/git/dcr/foo.fs(7,5): warning FS0058: Possible incorrect indentation: this token is offside of context started at position (6:7). Try indenting this token further or using standard formatting conventions.

1. Why does this warning occur at all? The [f#-spec p. 228](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.pdf) makes me think the token 'a' following '{' sets a new offside line, in which case there should be no problem?
2. Why does it occur twice?

Thanks,

Søren

Full output:

```
dcr > fsharpc foo.fs
F# Compiler for F# 3.0 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

/Users/debois/git/dcr/foo.fs(7,5): warning FS0058: Possible incorrect indentation: this token is offside of context started at position (6:7). Try indenting this token further or using standard formatting conventions.

/Users/debois/git/dcr/foo.fs(7,5): warning FS0058: Possible incorrect indentation: this token is offside of context started at position (6:7). Try indenting this token further or using standard formatting conventions.
dcr >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally worked it out. From the [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/about/files/spec.pdf) pp. 229–230, here are the pertinent rule about when offside contexts (lines) are introduced (rule numbering is mine):

> (i) The column of the first token of a (, { or begin token.
>
> (ii) Immediately after an = token is encountered in a record expression when the subsequent token either (a) occurs on the next line or (b) is one of try, match, if, let, for, while or use.

Now recall the problem:

```
//34567890
let r = {
  b = {      // line 6
    a = 2    // line 7 
  } 
}
```

The `b` on line 6 follows a `{` and so pushes an offside-line on column 3 by (i). Then, the `{` on line 6 follows a record expression `=` and so pushes a new offside line on column 7 by (ii). The `a` on line 7 column 5 violates that offside line.

The tricky bit is that the `{` on line 5 makes the *next* token define an offside-line, whereas the `{` on line 6 is *itself* an offside line (because it follows a record-expression equal sign).

Answer (score 4):

reformat your code as

```
type A = { a : int }
type B = { b : A }

//34567890
let r = { b = { a = 2 } }
```

or

```
let r =
    {
       b = { a = 2 } 
    }
```

i.e. the `{` is the left-most token.

EDIT: One off-site line starts with the `{` therefore you need to indent at least as much as the `{` the line break after is not mandatory. And the second warning is because of the same reason.

Comment: The former solution is impractical for larger records; the latter is workable, but gets into extreme indentation territory.

Either way: the question was *why* the compiler issues the warning? What did I do wrong originally?

Comment: I don't think that's the explanation. According to [the spec (link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233191.aspx) curly braces **do not** introduce new offside lines. The token _after_ a curly brace does, here `a`.

Comment: I suppose what you are looking for are the details around page 234 of the spec. And now I also noticed, you aligned the closing brace with the `let` itself, though it should be indented as well.

Comment: You'll forgive me, but I was hoping for some explanation about what rules are at play here, specifically why the first and second opening curly brace seems to have different behaviour when it comes to opening offside lines. (I looked at the spec around the page you suggested, but it only reaffirmed my belief that what I want should be legal.)

Answer (score 0):

Spec says:

Other structured constructs also introduce offside lines at the following places:

- The column of the first token of a (, { or begin token.

Why do you decide that offside line should be introduced by the token *after* the { when spec says that it should be the { itself?

NOTE: I agree that phrase "first token of ...token " sounds confusing. More likely it should be "first character of ...token" as this is applicable to begin\end case (offside line is introduced by the column of 'b' character)

```
begin
 begin
end // possible incorrect indentation: this token is offside of the context started at (2,2)
end
```

Having two warnings for the same position looks like a bug.

Comment: As you point out, the spec is a bit weird here. I don't think it says that the '{' itself begins the offside line, though. [Microsoft's Formatting Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233191.aspx), 6th bullet on the page, clarifies that it should be read 'first token after'.